# How to change hue of selected range in Android opencv?

Tags: android, opencv, image-processing

I am writing a program where I can change a specific color range to another color, eg- changing green to blue.
I have used Core.inRange function and my desired pixels are captured but now I want to change only the hue of the selected color pixel,

```
@Override
public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
    int cols = mHsv.cols();
    int rows = mHsv.rows();

    int xOffset = (view.getWidth() - cols) / 2;
    int yOffset = (view.getHeight() - rows) / 2;

    int x = (int)motionEvent.getX() - xOffset;
    int y = (int)motionEvent.getY() - yOffset;

    double[] data = mHsv.get(x, y);
    int i = 12;
    int H, S, V;
    H = (int) data[0];
    S = (int) data[1];
    V = (int) data[2]; 

    Mat thresh=new Mat();
    Core.inRange(mHsv, new Scalar(H - i, 0, 20), new Scalar(H + i, 255, 255), thresh);
    Utils.matToBitmap(thresh,mBmp);
    mImageView.setImageBitmap(mBmp);

    return false;
}
```

Comment: What's not working? What have you tried? Please *add a question* to the end of your post, explaining what you want help with.

Comment: @GezaKerecsenyi - after this point I don't know how to proceed further. My question is how I can change the hue which i got and display in a bitmap.